# Javascript window.open() escaping ampersands

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, popup

I am upgrading a legacy application and it uses the annoying practice of using Javascript `window.open()` to open popup windows in order to set values.  I'm having a problem passing querystring variables to that popup window, since the url is built server side.

Example

JS:

```
function popupwindow(vLink) { 
    window.open(vLink, 'Detail','width=600px,height=545px,status=yes,help=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=350');
}
```

XML

```
<asp:Label ID="lblOpener" runat="server" Text="_"></asp:Label>
```

Server Side

```
int ditem = 123;
string dcode = "ABC";
string vLink = string.Format("detail.aspx?item={0}&code={1}", ditem, dcode);
lblOpener.Attributes.Add("onclick", "popupwindow('" & vLink & "');");
```

When the label is clicked I am expecting the popup to open with the querystring:

`http://detail.aspx?item=123&code=ABC`

Instead, I get something like this:
`http://detail.aspx?item=123&amp%3bcode=ABC`

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try encoding using a [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx):

```
lblOpener.Attributes.Add("onclick", "popupwindow(" & New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(vLink) & ");");
```

Comment: Great solution.  Now that I think about it that makes perfect sense... if you want to encode something for Javascript you should probably serialize it with a JavaScriptSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

Will encodeURI work? Wrap your  `vLink` like so:

```
lblOpener.Attributes.Add("onclick", "popupwindow('" & encodeURI(vLink) & "');");
```

Might work!

Comment: This does not work.  I tried this when searching around. It encodes everything, even the "=", and creates an unsafe url.